# Sincronizando a Base de Dados no Desktop e Mobile?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, postgresql, mobile

Bom vou começar a trabalhar em um projeto GRANDE, que será MULTIPLATAFORMA, tanto pra Desktop e Mobile, e estamos discutindo uma maneira, de trabalhar com a BASE DE DADOS em ambas aplicações. As interações seriam mais ou menos como o FACEBOOK.

1. Todo UPDATE no BD via Desktop, deve ser notificado no Celular & Tablet. Igual quando um amigo do FACE compartilha algo e você é notificado.
2. Um chat sempre sincronizado em ambas plataformas.

Gostaria de saber como fazer isso? Estavamos discutindo em construir nossa aplicação em PHP e PostgreSQL, o que vocês acham? Já aproveitando, onde vocês recomendam hospedar essa aplicação? Estava pensando na Digital Ocean? Lembrando que a aplicação Desktop me refiro a um SITE.

Comment: Versão *mobile* também é um site, porém acessado pelo navegador do celular, tablet e similares, que pode ter a mesma apresentação do desktop ou uma forma reduzida. No caso você se refere à criação de um APP?

Comment: Sim! Desculpe talvez não ter sido muito claro. Me refiro a um APP!!

Comment: A não ser que seja algo interno, procure manter o mínimo de informações possíveis no dispositivo mobile, como informações importantes e privilegiadas, etc...
Apenas o necessário para que não consuma banda em excesso. Utilize serviços como rest, soap e outros. Caso contrário, terá que adequar a modelagem do seu banco de dados para atender as necessidades de um banco bidirecional, como controle de campos e tabelas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deveria fazer da seguinte forma:

Guarda tudo no banco postgres e acessar as informações via JSON no dispositivo mobile.
Então, quando você fizesse um update no banco, avisaria via o proprio JSON emitindo uma notificação.

Para o chat, você utiliza sempre o metodo get e POST para receber e enviar os dados.

Mas, se você quiser que o usuario visualize as informações offline, você deve criar um banco sqlite no mobile e guardar a informação nele.

Sobre a Digital Ocean, eu tenho um servidor com eles e recomendo totalmente.